# Why am I getting this runtime error? Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++, sorting, runtime-error

I am getting this runtime error while solving [this question](https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/) on leetcode.

> Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9

Here is my code-

```
class Solution {
public:
    double findMedianSortedArrays(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) 
    {
        int m=nums1.size();
        int n=nums2.size();
        vector<int> nums3;
        int i=0,j=0,k=0;
        while(i<m && j<n)
        {
            if(nums1[i]<=nums2[j])
                nums3[k++]=nums1[i++];
            else
                nums3[k++]=nums2[j++];
        }
        while(i<m)
            nums3[k++]=nums1[i++];
        while(j<n)
            nums3[k++]=nums2[j++];
        if(k%2==0)
            return ((nums3[k/2] + nums3[(k/2)-1])/2);
        else
            return nums3[k/2];
    }
};
```

Comment: At the point of the break, use the debugger to obtain a stack trace. That will lead back to your code, and then you can see what operation your code was doing that triggered the error.

Comment: Fun fact: when I searched for the error message (`[c++] "reference binding to null pointer of type"`), it seemed like all of the hits were questions from people trying to solve Leetcode problems. Strange coincidence, or something more systematic about the quality of Leetcode as a resource?

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> nums3;
```

This creates a new vector object. It is completely empty. There's nothing in it.

```
nums3[k++]=nums1[i++];
```

This attempts to modify the ***existing value*** of something in `nums3` by assigning it a value from `nums1`. There are no values in `num3`, its `size()` is 0, so this is undefined behavior and the reason for your crash.

A vector's `[]` operator accesses an ***existing*** value in the vector. It does not add anything to the vector. Contents to a vector are added by using `push_back()`, or maybe by `resize()`ing the vector.

Comment: Ok so I changed the code to `nums3.push_back(nums1[i++]);` and I am still getting the  same error.

Comment: Did you update ***only this*** line, or every one of them? Do you really understand what the issue is, what part of my answer is unclear? In any case, I can only respond to the code shown in the question, and not some modified version of it that's not shown.

Comment: Yes I changed all the 4 lines where nums3[k] was being assigned directly. I changed all those lines to nums3.push_back(); Still getting the error.

Comment: `Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x602000000130 overflowed to 0x60200000012c (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34`

This is the RE I am getting now

Comment: You can decode the error message: An offset overflowed from `0x6020000000000130` to `0x60200000012c`, so you must have added `0xfffffffffffffffc`. Perhaps your array index was negative? If you replaced all of the `num[k++]` with `num.push_back()` and made no other accommodations, then `k` will be zero at the end of the function. You could have found this if you used a debugger and looked at where the error was reported, then inspected the variables.

Comment: Yes you are right @RaymondChen I didn't increment k. I am new to actually solving questions on coding sites and I have never used a debugger before. I don't even know how to use it. Will do from now on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is exactly what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer. It is simply not possible to write code of any significant length without a debugger.